# Why does my callback get called before the fetch result is logged?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an async function that I wish to wait for until it's done and then make a log as such :

```js
function functionOne(_callback) {
  let fetchRes = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  
  fetchRes.then(res => res.json()).then(d => {
    console.log(d)
  })
  _callback();
}

function functionTwo() {
  // Do some asynchronus work.
  functionOne(() => {
    console.log("I am a callback, I should come last");
  });
}

functionTwo();
```

However the output is:

```js
"I am a callback, I should come last"

{
  completed: false,
  id: 1,
  title: "delectus aut autem",
  userId: 1
}
```

How can I make `console.log` wait for the async function to run in full before running? This code is available in a [JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/goq0b2ct/38).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling the `_callback` before the `promise` resolves. To fix it, just call the `_callback` inside the `then` method of the `promise`.

The new `.js` code:

```
function functionOne(_callback) {
  let fetchRes = fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  fetchRes.then(res =>
    res.json()).then(d => {
      console.log(d)
      _callback();
    })
}

function functionTwo() {
  // do some asynchronus work 
  functionOne(() => {
    console.log("I am a callback, I should come last");
  });
}

functionTwo();
```

Or you can implement `async` and `await` syntax:

```
async function functionOne(_callback) {
  let res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  let d = await res.json()
  console.log(d)
  _callback()
}

function functionTwo() {
  // do some asynchronus work 
  functionOne(() => {
    console.log("I am a callback, I should come last");
  });
}

functionTwo();
```

More information here: https://javascript.info/async-await.

Comment: It's a good answer, but since the OP is using promises, why have the callback at all?